# Moving Facebook C# SDK configuration settings to Azure ServiceConfiguration.cscfg

Tags: azure, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook C# SDK for an ASP.NET MVC Facebook Canvas application that I'm hosting in Windows Azure.

I currently have the Facebook C# SDK specific configuration settings (`appSecret`, `appId`, etc.) in `web.config`, but I would like to move them to the service configuration file instead so that I can alter the settings when moving from Staging to Production in Azure.

(How) can this be done? Right now I'm using the `CanvasAuthorize` attribute that automatically reads from `web.config`.

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = FacebookPermissions.ReadStreamPermission)]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Authenticate"); // Logged in, proceed with authentication
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Facebook C# SDK looks up at the configuration sections in web.config.

You will need to override the default Facebook application using code similar to this.

```
FacebookApplication.SetApplication(new DefaultFacebookApplication { AppId = "..", AppSecret = ".." });
```

The best place to set the application is at Application_Start.

You can checkout the sample at https://gist.github.com/820881

This means you are not tied to web.config. You can use database, azure service configuration or anything depending on your logic from where the settings can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reasoning of putting application specific configuration information in the Azure ServiceConfiguration.csfg file. Furthermore, I would say that this will be a problem rather than helpful to switch VIP's in the Azure control panel.
They way I do it is to have multiple web deployment configurations in my (ASP.NET MVC canvas page) Visual Studio project.  One for Staging and one for Production.

I use the [web.config transformation functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) in the Web Deployment to have different web.config settings for Staging/Production.
It works very well and smoothly, just right-click on the project, select Deploy and choose if you want to deploy to staging or production. You can also handle a specific testing AppID for Staging this way.

EDIT: I haven't looked in the source code for the Facebook C# SDK, but I would guess that the web.config read methods are, in fact, hard coded to use the web.config. That would also be a reason to keep it there.